# Is there notation for an function being undefined?

Tags: notation

I could think of $\lnot\exists x. f(y)=x$, but that seems hacky.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by undefined?

Comment: As per answer below, we have a notation for functions that are not defined for certain inputs. But an "undefined" expression in general is an expression without meaning, i.e. an expression not well-written. Thus, it makes little sense to write a "wrong" expression ...

Comment: Currently the word "undefined" here is undefined. Post the definition, that you are using, please.

Comment: Can an "undefined" thing been "defined". Seems unlogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematical logic, especially computability theory, the up-arrow "$\uparrow$" (LaTeX code "\uparrow") is used this way when talking about partial functions; if $p$ is a partial function and is not defined on input $e$, we write "$p(e)\uparrow$."

*This brings with it a notion of equality for partial functions/expressions, for which we use the symbol "$\simeq$" (LaTeX code "\simeq"). For individual expressions $x,y$ we say $x\simeq y$ iff either $x$ and $y$ are both undefined, or $x$ and $y$ are both defined and are equal, and for partial functions $p,q$ we say $p\simeq q$ if $p(i)\simeq q(i)$ for all valid inputs $i$.*

However, I haven't seen this notation used this way outside of logic.

Comment: Maybe also mention $f(x)=\bot$?